# R - Evaluate function stored in column of data.table

Tags: r, function, data.table

I have a data.table that looks as follows:

```
group my_function test_value

1     <function>          11
2     <function>          11
3     <function>          11
```

For each group I have a specific function stored in the column *my_function* that I would like to call with the argument *test_value*. The function is a custom function based on *approxfun*.

How do I do that? R complains about not finding the function when I call it using the column name. I'm working on a minimum reproducible example, but that might take a while.

I have tried:

```
dt[, new_val := map(test_value, ~my_function(.x))]
dt[, new_val := lapply(my_function, test_value)]
dt[, new_val := (my_function)(test_value)]
dt[, new_val := my_function(test_value)]
```

Comment: what have you tried? and is the function an R function (like mean) or a custom one? Is the custom one sourced/loaded?

Comment: Try `dt1[, Map(function(x, y) x(y), my_function, test_value)]`

Comment: If it is to call the entire 'test_value' column then `dt1[, lapply(my_function, function(x) x(test_value))]`

Comment: @RAB, I added the infos to the post. Function is an approxfun. I'm trying akrun's two suggestions right now.

Comment: @akrun, your first suggestion works, thanks! Could you please also explain what this exactly does?

Comment: It is looping over each element of the my_function(assuming it is a list of functions), and apply it to corresponding elements of 'test_value'

Comment: Since it looks like your first attempt was with `purrr` you might be interested to know `df[, new_val := invoke_map(my_function, test_value)` would also work

Comment: also ```dt$new_value <-purrr::map2_dbl(dt$test_value, dt$my_function, ~.x %>% .y)``` (if your expected output is a ```dbl```.. not sure what your function looks like